# Maven Dependency Spring Classpath Issue

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, classpath

So basically using the pom shown below, I am ending up with 2 versions of Spring in my WEB-INF/lib folder (3.1 and 3.0.5, and even on 3.0.6 oddly enough). I am assuming that spring-ws is the cause of this, so I tried to add exclusions so that it would not download older versions to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>  
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.3</version>  
            <scope>runtime</scope>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>  
            <version>2.0</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>  
            <version>2.0.3</version>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>LicensingSOAPService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Edit to show new pom after adding more exclusions.

Comment: Yeah, I see in mvnrepository that spring-ws depends on spring jars, but that's why I added the exclusions. Should that not keep these other versions from being inserted into my lib folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

this will reveal the following effective dependencies of `spring-ws` in your current configuration:

```
+- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
```

Now you know what has to go inside `<exclusion>`. Another approach is to get rid of all exclusions and simply declare dependencies in newer version explicitly, which will override transitive dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Once again experiment with `mvn dependency:tree`, it will guide you.

Comment: Well, I ran that and indeed see those dependencies, but even after adding them in the exclusions I am still getting the 3.0.5 AND 3.0.6 Spring jar files. Nothing else in the dependency list depends on spring jars so it has do with the spring-ws, but the either im missing something, or it is refusing to obey me and not exclude its own dependencies. EDIT: I even ran the mvn dependency:tree again, and no more spring jars show up under spring-ws. How the hell are these other jars getting shoved in there?

Comment: Tomasz, if you could further elaborate on what more I an do with dependency:tree I would love to try it, but as of now, no more spring jars are listed when I run the command, and yet I am still geting 3.0.5 and 3.0.6 spring jars in my classpath.

Comment: If you use Eclipse (with maven plugin) then you can have a dependency tree (Tab on pom editor). This will show you where the reference to this libs come from.

Comment: Trying the eclipse plugin now.

Comment: So, even under dependency hierarchy in eclipse, I see no mention of the any spring jars OTHER than 3.1 ones. How is it possible that maven is sweeping the older versions into my lib folder? Any help at all would be very much appreciated. Thanks..!

Answer (score 2):

I have copied you pom in a new project. And there is no Spring 3.0.x dependency left!

So may you only have an refresh problem.

```
mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ test2 ---
[INFO] test2:test2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:compile
```